# Changing text attribute based upon event handler in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've generated a series of circles and a text field based upon the follow data. See code below.

```
var data = [{"x":534.720996869109,"y":188.402300350323,"label":"ATP","size":5},
{"x":526.793135268385,"y":494.495864118909,"label":"PK","size":10},
{"x":539.854817710164,"y":332.435549874068,"label":"rpoA","size":10},
{"x":528.357841173126,"y":236.960433131191,"label":"rpoB","size":10}]

var width = 1000,height = 1000;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
       .domain([0, 1000])
       .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 1000])
    .range([0, height]);

var svgContainer = d3.select("body")
.append("svg:svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height",height);

//text
var text = svgContainer.selectAll("text")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("text");

var textbAttributes =   text
.attr("x", 800)
.attr("y", 100)
.text(function(d) { return ''})
.attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
.attr("font-size", "20px")
.attr("fill","black");

//circles
var nodesGroup = svgContainer.append("g");

var nodes = nodesGroup.selectAll("circle")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("svg:circle");

var nodeattr = nodes
.attr("cy", function(d,i){return y(d.y);  })
.attr("cx", function(d,i){return x(d.x); }) 
.on("click", function(){
    d3.select("text")
    .text(function(d,i){return d.label;})
    })
.attr("r", function(d,i){return d.size;});
```

I would like to be able to refresh the textfield with the corresponding data element "label" in the svg text element "text" upon clicking the circle. However the code above only returns the 1st label element regardless of the circles i click. Appreciate all help. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do with the text elements - you are creating a text element for every data item, all on top of each other at the same coordinates.

My guess is that you want one text element that displays the label of the circle that has been  clicked on? If this is the case you can change the creation of your text elements to just a single element:

```
//text  
var text = svgContainer.append("text")
    .attr("x", 800)
    .attr("y", 100)
    .text('')
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("font-size", "20px")
    .attr("fill","black");
```

And you can change the circle click handler to:

```
.on("click", function(d){d3.select("text").text(d.label);})
```

Working example here http://jsfiddle.net/yyESt/

Is this what you are trying to do?